# Reading the csv file containing Georgian Text

Tags: python, pandas

i want to read csv file which  contains georgian texts, i know that inside read csv i should use  encoding function like this :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data =pd.read_csv("HCIP.csv",engine='python', encoding='mac_latin2')
print(data.head())
```

i took possible values from the given link :

```
https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings
```

i have tried several options, like Western  and eastern Europe , but getting following result :
[image]

please if you seen such question before and know solution, help me . thanks in advance

for example text is like this :
[image]

with help of guys, i saved  excel file with format of Utf-8 and here is my screenshot

[image]

Comment: Do you have an example of the source text?

Comment: yes of course , i would add

Comment: The example looks like a part of a spreadsheet. How did you save it as CSV?

Comment: directly using save as command

Comment: A spreadsheet application should normally offer options for encoding (and other things) when saving as CSV. Which application do you use, by the way?

Comment: MIcrosoft Excel, so do you think that i  should format it?

Comment: On saving it should provide you a way to configure the encoding of the CSV (maybe with an additional button, I'm not used to Excel very much).

Comment: Will you please provide a link to your spreadsheet? I solved a similar recently and can solve this one as well :)

Comment: thanks guys, i saved it as Utf-8 and i will show now updated link

Comment: It would be more helpful to solve this if you post actual text -- not an image of it.

Comment: i solved it already, thanks in advance